# SQL updating values from reference table

Tags: sql

I have the two tables below.

[image]

I need help getting the following output:

[image]

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Can you give the query I just proved a made and let me know what the out come was? @MrClean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct t.No,
       t.ReportDate,
       t.OpNo,
       r.Definition as MethodOper
from tblRefCodes r
 inner join table1 t on t.Methodoper = r.Code
```

Comment: It works, but what if table 1 has more columns I want to pull. Is there a way to get them also without specifying them directly? I apologize I am really new to this.

Comment: @MrClean t.* would give you all of the columns in table1

Comment: If you are new to SQL, I highly recommend looking at w3schools.com, I think it is a great reference to use to get started with SQL. @MrClean